# How can I remove the default onCancel confirmation prompt in CKEDITOR dialogs?

Tags: ckeditor

When using ckeditor links, images and table properties dialogs if the user clicks on cancel, CKEDITOR will check if anything has changed and if so prompts the user with js confirm popup.

How can I disable this prompt on cancel; no other dialogs in our webapp prompts on cancel and this is not consistent.

There doesn't' seem to be a way to get a list of all the handlers for an event to remove the one that's doing the prompt.

I don't want to specify a custom isChanged for each and every dialog item to hack a fake nothings changed.

Is there a standard way to override the base on('cancel',...) event handlers in CKEDITOR? I see that I can monkeypatch the dialogdefinition.OnLoad, OnOK, OnCancel handlers but this forced cancel prompt I'm referring to is not being done in the dialog's OnCancel.

I'm using the latest version 4.2

Answer (score 3):

This is now a supported configuration option in version 4.3.  Just specify `config.dialog_noConfirmCancel = true` when you create the dialog.

Check out http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.config-cfg-dialog_noConfirmCancel

Answer (score 0):

You where very close. In fact it is in fact is the `onCancel` event.
There is a ticket for this problem that also includes a workaround:

```
CKEDITOR.on('dialogDefinition', function(dialogDefinitionEvent) {
    if (dialogDefinitionEvent.data.name == 'link') {
        var dialogDefinition = dialogDefinitionEvent.data.definition;
        // Get rid of annoying confirmation dialog on cancel
        dialogDefinition.dialog.on('cancel', function(cancelEvent) {
            return false;
        }, this, null, -1);
    }
});
```

If you leave out the `if (dialogDefinitioNEvent.data.name == 'link')` statement it would disable the check for all dialogs.

The `-1` handler parameter is the key here, as it inserts the handler before the dialog plugin's default handler, which will never be invoked because the `return false` cancels the bubbling of the cancel event to the other registered event listeners.

[CKEditor Ticket #8331: Ability to ignore "Confirm Cancel"-warning on dialogs](http://dev.ckeditor.com/ticket/8331#comment:3)

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm that the latest version of ckEditor works with the "noConfirmCancel" attribute.

A snippet of my working code is as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="#ckBasePath#/ckeditor.js" language="JavaScript"></script>
<script>
    thisConfig = CKEDITOR.config;
    thisConfig.autoParagraph = true;
    thisConfig.fillEmptyBlocks= true;
    thisConfig.dialog_noConfirmCancel = true;
    objSample = CKEDITOR.replace( 'Sample' , thisConfig);
</script>
```

http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.config-cfg-dialog_noConfirmCancel

Comment: Instead of adding a "new answer" you should have upvoted the existing answer that provides this info because other people will wonder what's the difference between your answer and that one.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.  My reputation score doesn't allow up voting yet (probably to prevent people from creating fake accounts and up voting their own answers) but I will continue to try when possible. I appreciate your guidance all the same :).